# How to filter a non-scalar type in AppSync / Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I am using aws-amplify to define my appsync schema.

I have following **simplified** schema:

```
type Country @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  code: String!
  tracks: [Track] @connection(name: "CountryTrack")
}

type Track @model
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  country: Country! @connection(name: "CountryTrack")
  lng: Float
  lat: Float
  length: Float
  curves: Int
  website: String
  trackImage: String
  information: String
}
```

Amplify generates the FilterInput for the models. However it does not include the connection types.

I want to filter a Track based on the Country.

The dynamodb tables does have a `trackCountryId` and in the scan operation I can simply filter based on the id.

However this does not work in the graphql schema. Because the `trackCountryId` is not included into the FiterInput.

Does anyone know how to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Amplify CLI creates `listTracks` query+resolver, and `tracks` resolver on the `Country` type, out of the box. If you would like to filter *all* Tracks based on a countryId, you would have to add this manually in the following steps, which are essentially a mix of the above generated query+resolvers:

-> **In your Schema**: Add this within the `type Query`, and then click on "Save Schema":

```
listTracksByCountry(countryId: ID!, limit: Int, nextToken: String, sortDirection: ModelSortDirection): ModelTrackConnection
```

-> **Attach a Resolver** to this query field you just added, and click on "Save Resolver":

- Pick the **TrackTable** as your Data source name
- **RequestMapping template**:

```
#set( $limit = $util.defaultIfNull($context.args.limit, 10) )
{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "Query",
  "query": {
      "expression": "#connectionAttribute = :connectionAttribute",
      "expressionNames": {
          "#connectionAttribute": "trackCountryId"
    },
      "expressionValues": {
          ":connectionAttribute": {
              "S": "$context.args.countryId"
      }
    }
  },
  "scanIndexForward":   #if( $context.args.sortDirection )
    #if( $context.args.sortDirection == "ASC" )
true
    #else
false
    #end
  #else
true
  #end,
  "filter":   #if( $context.args.filter )
$util.transform.toDynamoDBFilterExpression($ctx.args.filter)
  #else
null
  #end,
  "limit": $limit,
  "nextToken":   #if( $context.args.nextToken )
"$context.args.nextToken"
  #else
null
  #end,
  "index": "gsi-CountryTrack"
}
```

- **ResponseMapping template**:

```
#if( !$result )
  #set( $result = $ctx.result )
#end
$util.toJson($result)
```

-> Navigate to the **Queries** section on the Console, and run the following query:

```
query {
  listTracksByCountry(countryId: "countryId1") {
    items {
      id
      name
      length
    }
  }
}
```

You should be able to get a list of tracks for the countryId you specified. In my case, the GraphQL output for the above operation was:

```
{
  "data": {
    "listTracksByCountry": {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "trackId1",
          "name": "track name 1",
          "length": 1.1
        },
        {
          "id": "trackId2",
          "name": "track name 2",
          "length": 1.2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This seems to be a very common use case, so feel free to create an issue [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues), if it doesn't exist already, and we can then have Amplify CLI (`amplify add api`), generate these resolvers automatically.